# ActiveMQ isuue : Puppet Mcollective ping failing

Tags: activemq-classic, puppet, rhel6, mcollective

Seeing the following error message wen starting ActiveMQ

```
  2019-05-14 15:25:35,302 | INFO  | For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
  2019-05-14 15:25:35,815 | INFO  | ActiveMQ WebConsole available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/ | org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsoleStarter | main
  2019-05-14 15:25:35,867 | INFO  | Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher' | /admin | main
  2019-05-14 15:25:36,100 | INFO  | jolokia-agent: No access restrictor found at classpath:/jolokia-access.xml, access to all MBeans is allowed | /api | main
  2019-05-14 15:25:39,320 | ERROR | Could not accept connection from null: java.io.IOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error | org.apa
```

che.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-1

```
  2019-05-14 15:25:51,900 | ERROR | Could not accept connection from null: java.io.IOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-1
  2019-05-14 15:25:59,936 | ERROR | Could not accept connection from null: java.io.IOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-1
  2019-05-14 15:26:01,366 | ERROR | Could not accept connection from null: java.io.IOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-1
  2019-05-14 15:26:03,288 | ERROR | Could not accept connection from null: java.io.IOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-1
```

`mco ping` is failing because of this with below error

```
 error 2019/05/14 15:46:13: activemq.rb:149:in `on_ssl_connectfail' SSL session creation with stomp+ssl://mcollective@Node-001.wiley.com:61614 failed: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I had to upgrade puppet to latest version . Since Mcollective is deprecated in latest version, we are now using ansible for orchestration

Comment: You should also consider Puppet Bolt as an alternative to MCollective.